# Compute the derivative of the Dirac expectation of a norm

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, normed-spaces, dirac-delta

I want to compute the derivative of $R$ with respect to $a$

$$
R = \int\delta_0(x) || \nabla_x(ax+b)||^2
dx$$

I am not sure what to do. Whenever I start I get a weird result. For example:
$$
 \nabla_x(ax+b) = a
$$

$$
 ||\nabla_x(ax+b)||^2 = a
$$
$$
R=a
$$
Can someone please correct me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would see it like that:
\begin{align}
R &= \int\delta_0(x) ||\nabla_x(ax+b)||^2\,\text{d}x=||a||^2\int\delta_0(x) \,\text{d}x=||a||^2\\
\frac{\partial R}{\partial a}&=2||a||\frac{\partial ||a||}{\partial a}=2||a||\frac{a}{||a||}=2a
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful